# Moving files to new Image Set in Images.xcassets

Tags: xcode, xcode6

In Images.xcassets I've created a new Image Set (called mapView) in Xcode 6.

How do I move the current images (50T,60T,t40, map32, map32(1)) in Images.xcassets to my new Image Set called mapView?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the images from the asset catalog
2. Open mapView catalog
3. Rename images to have mapView in the title
4. Drag images into the mapView catalog

A decent 3-minute tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_36Y6rDcKP0